# jq parsing value with extension .tgz

Tags: python, json, shell, jq

Im trying to get values in with file extension "**.tgz**" with regular expression. But getting the jq error.

```
json_var=[ { "Key": "raw/bene/test/nd_OneP4.tgz" }, { "Key": "raw/bene/test/nd_OneP4.tgz" } ]

echo $json_var | jq -r ' .[] | to_entries | map(select(.key | test("*.tgz")).value)'
```

Jq error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): number (0) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
```

Comment: I tried this but not getting any results echo $json_var | jq '.[] | select(.id| tostring |test(".*.(tgz$)|(tar.gz$)")) | .key'

Comment: Hack alert! If you replace all the double quotes with newlines, you can easily find lines ending in `tgz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when setting json_var, you need to quote the string:

```
json_var='[ { "Key": "raw/bene/test/nd_OneP4.tgz" }, { "Key": "raw/bene/test/nd_OneP4.tgz" } ]'
```

Second, there's no need to use `to_entries`: the string you want to test is accessible via `.Key`:

```
echo $json_var |
  jq -r ' .[] | select(.Key | test("\\.tgz$")).Key'
```

Notice also the the argument of `test` must be the JSON representation of a regex.

Third, in your particular case at least, the above can be simplified to:

```
echo $json_var | 
  jq -r ' .[][] | select( test("\\.tgz$"))'
```